# TransitionFunction_linear is not a function

Tags: dart, dart2js, stagexl

Output code from dart2js throws exception before it runs my code.

Line of code: $.TimelineTween__linearEase = Z.TransitionFunction_linear$closure();

$ is undefined

Z is dart

Performed in Isolate loading.

mozilla: TypeError: Z.TransitionFunction_linear$closure is not a function

chrome: Object # has no method 'TransitionFunction_linear$closure'

Comment: Well I guess the most obvious question to ask here is if it is really a function versus being a method or field.

Comment: What does your application do? What libraries do you use. How did you build to JS.

Comment: Is this from StageXL?

Comment: Probably it is from stageXL.

Comment: I have an application built on StageXL. I am building js by pub build with options: transformers:
 - $dart2js:
    checked: true
    minify: false
    verbose: true
    analyzeAll: true
    suppressWarnings: false
    suppressHints: false
    terse: true

Comment: Sample application with stageXL imported do the same.